# How to pass Sonarqube exception test coverage

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, mockito

I'm passing the JUnit test but Sonarqube keeps informing me that my method is not covered by my tests. 
Here is my test method:

```
@Test(expected = DataNotFoundException.class)
public void testNullApplicationData() {
    appFilter.setApplicationId(null);
    appFilter.setPolicyNumber(null);

    Mockito.when(impl.getApplication(appFilter, null)).thenThrow(DataNotFoundException.class);
    assertNotEquals(null, impl.getApplication(appFilter, null));
}
```

And here is the method that I'm testing:

```
@Override
public ApplicationData getApplication(ApplicationFilter filter, String systemId) {
    try {
        ApplicationData appData = retrieveAppData(filter, systemId);
        if (Objects.isNull(appData)) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException(
                    StringUtils.join("Application ", ApplicationUtil.getApplicationFilterId(filter), " not found"));
        }

        return retrieveAppData(filter, systemId);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new DataException(
                StringUtils.join("Error retrieving application ", ApplicationUtil.getApplicationFilterId(filter)));
    }
}
```

**A few notes:**
I am certain that the `retrieveAppData(filter, systemId)` method will return a `null` result which will ensure that the `DataNotFoundException` will be triggered

I have not yet written a test method for the `DataAccessException` since I'm trying to figure out first how to pass the first exception in Sonarqube

Here are the commands I used when I built the project:
`mvn clean install`
`mvn clean package sonar:sonar`

Comment: You're not testing the `getApplication` method, you have mocked it away, hence it won't be covered. Unrelated to that but why do you have two call's to `retrieveAppData` in your method? You could simply return `appData` if it is not `null`.

Comment: Will it still not be covered even if I called it inside `assertNotEquals`?

Comment: The `retrieveAppData` point is actually good. I'm gonna change that. Thanks

Comment: Generally you do not want to mock things you are trying to test. Having a `assertNotEquals` or not does not matter. In you case (as you trying to test  the exception case) it doesn't have any impact on the test anyway, beside making it more confusing to read. If you want to mock something, you generally mock dependencies or parameters, but without knowing what `retrieveAppData` is actually doing I can't suggest anything here.

Comment: `retrieveAppData` is a private method. Its declared in the same class where the `getApplication` method is declared. I was having thoughts of mocking that as well but its a private method. By the way its a legacy code so I can't really touch that one. But what it does is it will pull results from a database based on the content values of the `ApplicationFilter` model

Comment: If you can't controll the return of the method based on the filter, then maybe you can mock the part that does the database interaction. But normally I would suggest that you do an integration test instead.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. I just changed `retrievedAppData` from private to public and everything was fixed. Thanks for the help. I'll post an answer later

Comment: Please add information what is `impl`. I need a line which assigns a value to it.